# how do i submit a form with a default value using get if nothing is selected?

Tags: php, html, get

this is my form :

```
$html = "";
$html .= "<div id='options'>";
$html .= "<form action='filter.php' method='get'>";
$html .= "<select multiple='multiple' name='options'>";
foreach($selectValues as $option){
    $html .= "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
}
$html .= "</select><input type='submit' value='submit'></form></div>";
```

but if i do not select an option from the box and i submit i get the error "Undefined index: options " i want to be able to submit and have it pass a defualt value if nothing is selected

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code that consumes the data from the form?

Comment: Why not just add a default option in the select that is set as selected? <option selected="selected" value="default">default</option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should probably fix your code in the backend instead to do a `!empty($_GET['options'])` check.** Secondly, your field name should be `options[]`, not `options`, as it will get overwritten with the last selected value (due to the way PHP handles input). Thirdly, you might want to `htmlspecialchars()` your `$option` when you output it. This ensures that weird options won't break your HTML. Finally, if your option has the same value as its label, you don't need to specify it as the value as well.

Comment: What you want to do is first check to see if the item exists and then if it's empty.  ie:  if(isset($_GET['options'] && !empty($_GET['options'])){ // do something }  else{  // set a default value }.   I believe "empty()" will throw an error if the variable was not set.

Comment: A simple `!empty($_GET['options'])` implies that the variable is set, and won't throw any undefined var or index notices. No need to use `isset()` with `!empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$html = "";
$html .= "<div id='options'>";
$html .= "<form action='filter.php' method='get'>";
$html .= "<select multiple='multiple' name='options'>";

$html .= "<option value='default'>Select An Option</option>";

foreach($selectValues as $option){
    $html .= "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
}
$html .= "</select><input type='submit' value='submit'></form></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the selected attribute on one of the option like so:

```
$html = "";
$html .= "<div id='options'>";
$html .= "<form action='filter.php' method='get'>";
$html .= "<select multiple='multiple' name='options'>";
foreach($selectValues as $option){
    $html .= "<option value='$option'" . ($option == 'my default option' ? ' selected="selected" : '') . ">$option</option>";
}
$html .= "</select><input type='submit' value='submit'></form></div>";
```

This is an immediate if that will check if the option is equal to "your default option" and add `selected="selected"` to the default option.

However, that will not work if the user unselects the options.

Before trying to use the $_GET['options'], you should always check if it's defined using isset.